# renaming elements of a duplicated character vector in a data.table and then to reshape the data

Tags: r, data.table, dplyr, tidyr

In a column of a data.table, I have duplicated elements. I would like to rename these consecutively in each group so that I can then use the dcast function. Let me explain with the following example:

```
DT <- data.table(v1 = letters[c(1,rep(4,3),10,1,rep(7,3),1,10,12)],  
             v2=month.abb[1:12],  
       v3=c("AV",rep("SINGLE",3),"DAT","AV",rep("SINGLE",3),"AV","DAT","R"),  
             v4 = c(3L, 2L, 2L, 5L, 4L, 3L,6L,11L,1L,7L,12L,20L))  
DT  
# I Want to create a new variable,"newv" where the factor,"SINGLE" in the variable (v3)      
# to be named sequentially with the first letter as 's' followed by an integer  

## unsuccessful attempt  
#DT[v3 == SINGLE", newv:= for (i in 1:.N) {paste0('s',i)}, by="v1"]  
# What I want is the following data table
DT1 <- data.table(v1 = letters[c(1,rep(4,3),10,1,rep(7,3),1,10,12)],
             v2=month.abb[1:12],  
v3=c("AV",rep("SINGLE",3),"DAT","AV",rep("SINGLE",3),"AV","DAT","R"),  
v4 = c(3L, 2L, 2L, 5L, 4L, 3L,6L,11L,1L,7L,12L,20L),  
newv=c("AV","s1","s2","s3","DAT","AV","s1","s2","s3","AV","DAT","R"))  

DT1
# Now proceeding with dcast
dt2<-DT1[,`:=`('v2'=NULL,'v3'=NULL)] # to get the right shape in the final result  
dcast.data.table(dt2,v1~newv,value.var="v4")
#Aggregate function missing, defaulting to 'length'
# Instead of the length, I would like to have the values from variable "v4"
# How do I get that?
```

Basically, I have not succeeded with my aims : (1) to rename the common factor "SINGLE" with a sequential string and (2) to reshape the data table to get the renamed strings, s1 to s3, as the column headers with the "v4" values appearing in the table.

I would appreciate any help that I can get. Either with data.table or dplyr/tidyr.

Comment: You should see the `rowid` function, using which you'd be able to skip creating `newv`.

Comment: If defaults to length because you have a grouping with more than one obs (the j ~ DAT one, with values 4 and 12). You can set some other function though, as explained in the `?dcast` docs.

Comment: It's not clear what do you expect from `dcast` to do. If in the same combination of `v1` and `new` you have several matching values in`v4` how should `dcast` know which one to pick? Regarding `newv`, a general solution could be `DT[, newv := if(.N > 1) paste0(v3, 1:.N) else v3, by = rleid(v3)]` or for slightly different output you could just do `DT[, newv := paste0(v3, rowid(v3)), by = rleid(v3)]`